# Session variable not Updating even after including session_start()

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have page named **train_detail.php**. I had a table on that page which was made using SQL and has **train_id** as one of its column attributes. At the end of each row there is a button named **check_availability**. When this button is clicked, a new modal will open. It will pass the row value(**train_id**) to the modal. I did that using JS by passing the value through post method to a page **helpe.php**. Now,I have made that $_SESSION variable and passed the value of $_POST variable to the SESSION variable.But the problem is that the session variable is not able to update its value. Please help me.

train_detail.php-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <style>
    .header{
        width: 70%;
    }
    .content {
        width: 70%;
    }
    <?php  
    session_start();
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
    $Source =$_SESSION['Source'];
    $Destination = $_SESSION['Destination'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM train_details WHERE train_source='$Source' AND train_destination='$Destination'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
?>

</style>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<style>
#myDIV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.hidden{
       display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Train details</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="content">


            <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Train no.</th>
            <th>Train name</th>
            <th>Train departure</th>
            <th>Train arrival</th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
        <script>
        function myFunction() {

}
        </script>
        <tbody>
        <!--Use a while loop to make a table row for every DB row-->
            <?php while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) : ?>
        <tr>
            <!--Each table column is echoed in to a td cell-->
            <td><?php echo $row["train_id"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["train_name"]; ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["train_departure"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["train_arrival"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="availability"  class=" open-AddBookDialog btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $row["train_id"]; ?>"
                href="#addBookDialog">Check availability</button>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        </tbody>
</table>    

        <!--modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="addBookDialog" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">


                    <p><?php echo $_SESSION['var_train2']  ?></p>
                    <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>

                    <div id="train">
                    </div>
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <?php
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM train_status WHERE 1";
                            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                            ?>
                            <?php while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) : ?>
                            <th><?php echo $row["train_date"]; ?></th>
                            <?php endwhile ?>       
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>availability</th>
                            <?php
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM train_status WHERE 1";
                            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                            ?>
                            <?php while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) : ?>
                            <th><?php echo $row["availability"]; ?><br>
                            <a href="login.php?logout='1'" style="color: blue;">book now</a></th>
                            <?php endwhile ?>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <script>
                        function myFunction() {
                        location.reload();

                        }
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
            var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
            $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );

            $.ajax({
            type: 'post', // the method (could be GET btw)
            url: 'helper.php', // The file where my php code is
            data: {
            'test': myBookId // all variables i want to pass. In this case, only one.
            },
            success: function(data) { // in case of success get the output, i named data
            alert(data); // do something with the output, like an alert
            }
            });
            }); 

        </script>   

            <p> <a href="login.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

helper.php-

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['test'])) { //if i have this post

    echo $_POST['test']+1; // print it   
    $_SESSION["var_train2"] =$_POST['test'];
    echo $_SESSION['var_train2'];

}
?>
```

Comment: are you trying to do  $_SESSION["var_train2"] =$_POST['test'] +1; ?

Comment: Is echo $_SESSION['var_train2'] giving you an output?

Comment: yes it is giving me an output.But that does not changes when i click on some other button.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two programming layers:

1. The PHP layer is processed on the **server** **before** any content is delivered to the client.
2. The JS layer is processed on the **client**, **after** the server has finished it's processing and the content has been delivered to the client.

So the **client** (JS) has no way whatsoever to read the content of any server var, including the ´$_SESSION´ vars. The **modal dialog** is displayed as part of the bootstrap (BS) framework **via JS** (hidden deep down in the BS code). It's displayed by purely using clientside JS code, with no extra server roundtrip. So the PHP in this line:

```
<p><?php echo $_SESSION['var_train2']  ?></p>
```

is processed **server** side, way **before** the user clicks any button, even before the client even receives any HTML. So assuming the session is empty at first the rendered HTML code looks like this:

```
<p></p>
```

Check in your browser's native HTML display (view source command) to verify. That's the reason, you do not see any value in your dialog, when you click your button.

So now, when your **client side** button get's clicked, you go and call the helper script in your AJAX call. This sets the ID of the button in the session var. What happens:

1. Pushing the button triggeres a **client side** JS script, that **cannot** set any `$_SERVER` var.
2. The JS script runs an AJAX call, requesting the **server side** helper script.
3. The **server side** helper script is executed on the **server** setting the `$_SESSION` var with content posted by the AJAX call.
4. The **server side** helper script terminates and the `$_SESSION` var now contains the new value.
5. The **client side** bootstrap part displays the modal dialog which still contains the original empty line:

`<p></p>`

Now you got one part of the deal, you've set the `$_SERVER` var. But it does not get displayed **client side** without a reload. To get the code displayed on the client you have multiple possibilities:

1. Put the modal dialog in a separate php file (dialog.php) and open that file in either in a browser popup window or in the browser main window, replacing the current content. Post the train ID to that dialog.php and read all you need from the database. You don't need any ajax here or any BS modal dialog.
2. Use the current BS modal dialog, but fill it's content using JS.

I won't elaborate on case 1, just on case 2:

Change the above line to contain an ID:

`<p id="myID"></p>`

In the onclick function use JQuery in addition to the existing code to set the content of the `<p id="myID"></p>` tag:

```
$(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
$("#myID").text(myBookId); // new
```

Now the dialog should display the ID of the according button. If you want more data to be loaded from the server via AJAX and displayed in the dialog, you might consider a framework like AngularJS to do the work for you. The learning curve there of course is a litte steeper.

Another (completely different) problem may be a possible SQL injection error in the line where you build the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM train_details WHERE train_source='$Source' AND train_destination='$Destination'";
```

This strongly looks like it is vulnerable to an SQL injection error. If e.g. someone sets source to somethimg malicious it could completely change the meaning of the query. You should either encapsulate your value with [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in the first place.

Comment: I'm sorry but are you telling me to create a kind of session variable using JS?and if possible can you please give me a snippet of what correct code could look like?

Comment: No, you are mixing 2 layers. You cannot, as you stated correctly, create session vars in JS nor can you read them in JS. You have to look at both layers, php and JS separately. I'll try to elaborate on it in the answer.